# Getting Failure/Error: Puppet::SSL::CertificateAuthority.new in puppet

Tags: ssl, rspec, puppet

I built the puppet from source code ,on a solo architecture with both puppet master and agent on the same node , when i run the rspec test cases , i am getting a lot of SSL certs issues , and almost all of the have same failure.

```
Puppet::Face[:ca, v0.1.0]   
     Failure/Error: Puppet::SSL::CertificateAuthority.new   
     Errno::EACCES:   
       Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/rspecrun20150617-23070-1ls4i9z/face-ca-ssldir20150617-23070-hwwl9f/ca/ca_key.pem   
     # ./lib/puppet/file_system/file_impl.rb:26:in `initialize'  
     # ./lib/puppet/file_system/file_impl.rb:26:in `open'  
     # ./lib/puppet/file_system/file_impl.rb:26:in `open'  
     # ./lib/puppet/file_system.rb:37:in `open'  
     # ./lib/puppet/settings/file_setting.rb:197:in `block in open'  
     # ./lib/puppet/settings/file_setting.rb:230:in `block (2 levels) in controlled_access'  
     # ./lib/puppet/util.rb:48:in `withumask'  
     # ./lib/puppet/settings/file_setting.rb:221:in `block in controlled_access'  
     # ./lib/puppet/util/suidmanager.rb:72:in `asuser'   
     # ./lib/puppet/settings/file_setting.rb:219:in `controlled_access'  
     # ./lib/puppet/settings/file_setting.rb:196:in `open'  
     # ./lib/puppet/indirector/ssl_file.rb:162:in `write'  
     # ./lib/puppet/indirector/ssl_file.rb:98:in `save'   
     # ./lib/puppet/indirector/indirection.rb:276:in `save'  
     # ./lib/puppet/ssl/host.rb:151:in `generate_key'   
     # ./lib/puppet/ssl/host.rb:197:in `certificate'   
     # ./lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_authority.rb:270:in `setup'  
     # ./lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_authority.rb:161:in `initialize'  
     # ./spec/integration/faces/ca_spec.rb:20:in `new'  
     # ./spec/integration/faces/ca_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Huh. Are you using SELinux?

Comment: no .. i am not using that , i am doing it RHEL 7.1

Comment: Let me rephrase that: Are you certain that SELinx is disabled on your RHEL System?

Comment: Oh .. ok got it.. Thought it as Suse Enterprise linux ,my Bad...  i checked the SELinux status on my machine , its enabled on my machine , do i need to disable it..?? is it because of that .. ?

Comment: I cannot fitfully answer that. SELinux *will* cause some access denials. That's what it's designed to do. Disabling it is usually not the *right* thing to do, but is often the most practical workaround. You have to weigh for yourself whether the added security is worth the (likely considerable) management overhead. (Which for you includes learning about SELinux in the first place - it's quite a complex subsystem.)

Comment: I tried disabling the SELinux and then re-ran the spec tests on my node,bu t no change .. its just the same.

Comment: any leads @FelixFrank..??

Comment: No you will have to debug that yourself. Try and find out the exact permissions of the directories and file and why it's not accessible. Side note: **Why** are you even running the spec tests? Are you patching Puppet and want to make sure you didn't break anything? Spec tests are not required or sensible for production setups.